# HTML Form Data When Opening a New Window

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

Let's say I'm doing a POST form, so I set my method and action like this:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My data is successfully transferred and everything is great. Now let's say I want to open a new window upon submission. Typically you'd do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" onSubmit="window.open('page.php', 'Submission', 'width=600,height=400,status=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=no'>
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But here is the conundrum: when you click submit, the pop-up window opens AND the form submits in the original window.

Question: does this window.open JS method work with the the POST action? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: You forgot to close window.open -> )"

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <textarea id="text" name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
    <script>
    function submit()
    {
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php?text="+text,
            success: function(html){ alert('POST OK'); window.open('http://www.google.com'); }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: But this will result the exact same problem I have now. It will complete the POST,pass the variable and then the window.open function opens a separate window. The window I want opened would be the same in the URL and window parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With return false, the form won't submit.

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" onSubmit="window.open('page.php', 'Submission', 'width=600,height=400,status=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=no'); return false;">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question - I need the form to submit but to pass the information into the pop-up window.